# pass by reference in java - editing the value in another function

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

why is the following code output equals 0?

```
public class A{


    public static void main(String [] args){

        int a=0;
        foo(a);
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void foo(int a){
        a=78;
    }


}
```

Comment: Mary, the answer you've accepted is incorrect.

Comment: Also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference (this may even be a duplicate of that question, although there are small differences).

Answer (score 5):

It outputs `0` because that's the value of `a` in the `main` function. Java is *entirely* pass-by-value, it doesn't have pass-by-reference at all. So when you call `foo`, the *value* of the `a` variable is passed into `foo`, not a reference to the `a` variable. `foo` then modifies the value of *its* `a` argument, but that has no effect whatsoever on the `a` variable in `main`.

You may hear people talk about "pass-references-by-value" or "pass-by-value-of-reference," which can be confusing and I strongly recommend avoiding that terminology like the plague. :-) But here's what they're talking about:

In your example, `a` is a *primitive*. The `a` variable *contains* the value `0`. But equally, you could do this:

```
 Object a = new Object();
 foo(a);
```

What gets passed to `foo` now? ***Exactly*** the same thing that was passed when it was an `int`: The *value* of `a`. The only difference is that now, the *value* of `a` is an object reference. Object references are just values like anything else; they tell the JVM where the data for the object is in memory. Think of them like indexes into a big array or something.

So where:

```
int a = 42;
```

gives us this in memory:

```
+---------+
|    a    |
+---------+
|   42    |
+---------+
```

this

```
Object a = new Object();
```

...gives us this:

```
+---------+
|    a    |             
+---------+             +-----------------+
| mumble  |------------>| The object data |
+---------+             +-----------------+
```

It's important to understand that `a` still just contains a value, just like when it contains an `int` or a `float`. It's just the *meaning* of that value which differs, just as the meaning of the value held by an `int` is different from the meaning of a value held by a `float`. In the case of an object reference, the meaning of the value is "the object is over there".

Just like you can have more than one variable holding the value `42`, you can have more than one variable holding a reference to the same object:

```
int a, b;
a = 42;
b = a;
```

gives us

```
+---------+     +---------+
|    a    |     |    b    |
+---------+     +---------+
|   42    |     |   42    |
+---------+     +---------+
```

and so similarly

```
Object a, b;
a = new Object();
b = a;
```

gives us

```
+----------+     +----------+
|     a    |     |     b    |
+----------+     +----------+
|  mumble  |--+--|  mumble  |
+----------+  |  +----------+
              |
              |
              |    +-----------------+
              +--->| The object data |
                   +-----------------+
```

`a` and `b` still just contain values, like 42; but that value tells the JVM where the object is, and so they refer to (point to) the same object.

Getting back to `foo`, when you call a function, passing in an argument is *exactly* like assigning a variable to another variable, so think of `b` above as the `foo` function argument.

In the comments below, you've asked about arrays. Arrays are just like objects — or they *are* objects; choose your preferred semantics. :-) So:

```
int[] a;
int[] b;

a = new int[5];
b = a;
```

gives us:

```
+----------+     +----------+
|     a    |     |     b    |
+----------+     +----------+
|  mumble  |--+--|  mumble  |
+----------+  |  +----------+
              |
              |
              |    +----------------+
              +--->| The array data |
                   +----------------|
                   | [0]: 0         |
                   | [1]: 0         |
                   | [2]: 0         |
                   | [3]: 0         |
                   | [4]: 0         |
                   +----------------+
```

So consider:

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[5];
    foo(a);
    System.out.println(a[0]);
}

void foo(int[] b) {
    b[0] = 42;
}
```

That prints `42`. Why? Because the *value* of `a` was passed into `foo`, and so `b` within `foo` points to the same array that `a` points to. You can change the state of the object using the reference. Note that you're not changing the value of `b`, you're changing the state of the thing that `b` refers to.

Contrast with:

```
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[5];
    foo(a);
    System.out.println(a[0]);
}

void foo(int[] b) {
    b = new int[5]; // <==== change here
    b[0] = 42;
}
```

Now it prints `0`, because you've assigned a *new* value (a new object reference) to `b`, which has no effect on the value held by `a` or the thing that `a`'s value refers to.

Comment: ...I'm not sure I'd say that without qualification, i.e. "pass-references-by-value."

Comment: @LouisWasserman: The OP didn't mention object references, and I find they muddy the discussion because they think the word "reference" relates to pass-by-reference, which it doesn't.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, well the title explicitely mentions "pass by reference".

Comment: I hesitate to make sweeping generalizations like "_entirely_ pass-by-value" when that seems likely to further confuse the OP in the not-too-distant future.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/869736 manages to make the distinction very nicely clear, though.

Comment: @A.H.: Yes, and pass-by-reference has **nothing** to do with object references.

Comment: wait a second. but If I try to pass an Object meaning not a simple type then It's passed by reference?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Regading mary's last comment: And here we are. Is there _anyone_ who does _not_ saw this coming upfront?

Comment: and how do I do the swap function in java? why is it when I pass an array and I edit it's inside then it does change  the contents?

Comment: Upvoted for the _very_ thorough explanation, but I feel like there must be some answer we can just bookmark and link for anyone who asks this question.

Comment: @mary: No, the object reference is passed by value, and so both the original variable and the argument *refer to* the same object. That's not pass-by-refernce. See my updated answer. Your array example is an object reference being passed by value. Since the argument in the function has a copy of the object reference, it can change the object's state (including the entries in the array).

Comment: Bleahhhhhhh. @A.H., I concede.  I still think there should be One True Link for this, but that probably still wouldn't work.  Maybe http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm ?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I completely agree about the One True link. Surely there has to be a previous, clear, correct answer on this? :-)

Comment: @JohanSjöberg: Yeah, I went looking and found that too. Didn't think this was *quite* a duplicate of that, but the explanations there are good and we should highlight it for the OP. (Done)

Answer (score 3):

Because Java is strictly "Pass by value". And note *carefully*: Passing a reference by value is not the same as "Pass by Reference".

Answer (score 1):

Arguments in Java are always passed by value. 
Argument *a* in *foo* is not connected with vaiable *a* in *main*.

Answer (score 1):

Ya.
Because java is all pass by value
and i is a primitive type so the one that passed is his value which is 0 not his reference.

You can read the link below to easily understand how parameter are passed in java

http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling foo(a) inside main() method, it takes the value of a declared inside main() method and passes it to the argument of foo() method.

The argument of foo() will always act as local scoped variable to foo() method. So whatever you did inside it will never reflect inside main() method. So when you print it, it shows the value of a which was declared inside main() method locally.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. The confusion a lot of people suffer from is that if you're dealing with an Object (int is NOT an Object) then the value is actually a reference to the Object.

The following would work:

```
public class A{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        IntWrapper a = new IntWrapper(0);
        bar(a); // Pass a copy of the reference to a
        System.out.println(a.intValue);
    }

    public static void bar(IntWrapper iw) { // iw is a reference because IntWrapper is an Object
        iw.intValue = 78;
    }

    class IntWrapper { // Classes implicitly extend Object
        int intValue;

        IntWrapper(int value) {
            intValue = value;
    }
}
```